# R importing large .csv shows value although it should be a NA

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I'm importing a csv with 700k rows and R shows that there are no `NA` values, although the data has blank values and the code defines them as `NA`. Additionally when I filter a particular row that I know for sure that doesn't have a specific value, it shows a random value of the 2 available besides `NA`. Exporting the csv, after filtering, the file shows some blank values that R shows with a random value.
However, I tested the code with a small sample of the data and didn't have this problem, and the `NA`s were shown normally. What could be the problem? There's a solution or an alternative? I don't understand the difference in the size of the data that could generate that error in R.

The import code

```
DB <- read.csv("DB.CSV", sep = "~", header=FALSE,  na.strings = c(""))
```

The filter code

```
DB_MA <- DB %>% filter(ID_COM == 11001, REGISTER == "MA")
```

Export code

```
write.csv(DB_MA,"DB_MA.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: We have no data, have no proof or demonstration of your claims, so have no way to reproduce the issue. How do you believe we will be able to help?

Comment: Maybe someone could point out a better way to deal with a csv file of that size or find an error in my code. I don't expect more than that, so there's no need of proof.

Comment: Does this help ?  `DB_MA <- DB %>% filter(ID_COM %in% 11001, REGISTER %in% "MA")`

Comment: A file of "that size" is not really an issue, I'm regularly working on 2M row CSV files; a question I commented on earlier was discussing 15G of data in the CSV. While I find the use of `sep="~"` *nonstandard*, I've dealt with stranger, so it's not an error by any means. Your code provides no indication of problems. It's almost always aberrant *data* in the file that causes problems. I suggest you find rows that should have `NA` but instead don't, then paste those lines (as raw CSV, perhaps) into a code-block and then we can test the code you use to read it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's three MCVE that show that using a tilde as a separator does not change the behavior of `read.csv` with respect to how length-0 character values are handled by the `na.strings` parameter.

```
DB <- read.csv(text='a~b~""~d\ne~""f~g\n', sep = "~", 
               header=FALSE,  na.strings = c(""))
DB
#------------
  V1 V2   V3   V4
1  a  b <NA>    d
2  e  f    g <NA>
#--- Now use an explicit length-o character value---
DB2 <- read.csv(text='a~b~~d\ne~f~g\n', sep = "~", 
                header=FALSE,  na.strings = c(""))
DB2
#----------
  V1 V2   V3   V4
1  a  b <NA>    d
2  e  f    g <NA>
#---Now leave out the na.strings parameter so it is the default= "NA"
DB3 <- read.csv(text='a~b~~d\ne~f~g\n', sep = "~", 
                header=FALSE)
DB3
#-------
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  b     d
2  e  f  g   

nchar(DB3[1,3])
#[1] 0
```

I suspect you have some places where you have either an instance of `" "` or some non-printing character. You should be able to use the `nchar` function to examine those locations to test my hypothesis ( more of a firm prediction).